# delete multiple rails session variables in a single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code that deleted multiple variables, as such...

```
session.delete(:a)
session.delete(:b)
session.delete(:c)
session.delete(:d)
```

is it possible to delete them all in one go instead of 4 lines?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible. Check out one way using basic [Array#`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d].each { |x| session.delete(x) }
```

Comment: Even if the approach of the other answer is cleaner for this specific case, I like this one because it's everywhere applicable. :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work as well,

```
 session.delete([:a, :b, :c, :d])
```

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal it did not work for me. I believe I would've been working on a rails 5 project at the time, judging by the timestamp of my comment. Just verified on 5.2.0.alpha --- this does not remove session values stored under keys :a, :b, :c, :d

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal this checks the session hash for a value stored under the key `[:a, :b, :c, :d]`...e.g. `{ [:a, :b, :c, :d] => "turtles", a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }` --- only "turtles" value would be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @rthbound